# Creating a Container from ImageFromDockerfileBuilder with TestContainers .NET C#

Tags: c#, e2e-testing, testcontainers

I'm taking a stab at using the TestContainers package for my .NET application.  I have a Dockerfile authored for building the image that I need for my application.  I followed the instructions on the [documentation](https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/api/create_docker_container/):

```cs
var image = new ImageFromDockerfileBuilder()
    .WithDockerfileDirectory(CommonDirectoryPath.GetSolutionDirectory(), string.Empty)
    .WithDockerfile("Dockerfile")
    .Build();

await image.CreateAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

However, I'm unsure how to create and run a container using this newly built image.  The CreateAsync() call does not return a value and `image` is indicating that is an `IFutureDockerImage`.  I do see a new image being created locally in Docker Desktop after the CreateAsync() call completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WithImage()` method on `ContainerBuilder` accepts the `IFutureDockerImage` type that gets returned from calling on `ImageFromDockerfileBuilder.Build()`.

```cs
public static async Task<IContainer> CreateAndStartDatabaseContainer()
{
    var image = new ImageFromDockerfileBuilder()
        .WithDockerfileDirectory(CommonDirectoryPath.GetSolutionDirectory(), string.Empty)
        .WithDockerfile("Dockerfile")
        .Build();

    await image.CreateAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    var container = new ContainerBuilder()
        .WithImage(image)
        .WithPortBinding(9153, 3306)
        .WithEnvironment("stage", "e2e")
        .Build();

    await container.StartAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return container;
}
```

Comment: Your approach mentioned above is correct. After thinking about it again, it seems we can improve the API by enhancing the `DependsOn` API. We'd just need to accept an `IFutureDockerImage` and make sure it's created before the main container starts, like how the other `DependsOn(INetwork)`, etc. setups work. It may require some additional modifications to function properly with the image builder, but I believe it should work.